# Changing 3D Perspective Views using the NumPad

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I'm trying to use the number pad shortcuts to control the views, Left, Right, Back, etc. It isn't working, though. It only works when I click on the view through the menu.
[image: viewport]

Instead, these little boxes are lighting up.
[image: layers]

How can I make it so that my Number Pad keys will have the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking **Emulate Numpad** in the User Preferences(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: Awesome! And just for curiosity, is this only necessary on desktops?

Comment: If this helped you, please mark it as accepted(that gray check mark under the voting buttons.). No, this is not only necessary for desktops, it's used for laptops too. Also, not all desktops require this, mine doesn't.

Comment: It's actually quite strange this is necessary in your case, and that it even worked. This option normally makes it so the number row above the main keyboard can be used instead of a numpad (at the cost of some shortcuts which use those numbers, e.g. layer switching or subserf), but I guess not in this case..?

Comment: @gandalf3 my best bet is their is an issue in the keyboard drivers, or some compatibility issue.

Comment: Try pressing the NUM_LOCK button on your keyboard number pad.  Number pads have two modes and that button switches between them, at least for Windows that's how it is.  That button seems to have no effect under OSX and I'm not sure what happens with Linux.